# Modifying code so that it returns files aswell as subdirectories

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this code:

```
Function GetSubDir(ByVal sPath As String, Optional ByVal sPattern As Variant) As Variant

Dim sDir As String
Dim sDirLocationForText As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clk

If Right$(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

If IsMissing(sPattern) Then
sDir = Dir$(sPath, vbDirectory)
Else
sDir = Dir$(sPath & sPattern, vbDirectory)
End If
Do Until LenB(sDir) = 0

If sDir <> "." And sDir <> ".." Then
sDirLocationForText = sDirLocationForText & ";" & sPath & sDir
End If
sDir = Dir$

Loop

If Left$(sDirLocationForText, 1) = ";" Then sDirLocationForText = 
Right(sDirLocationForText, Len(sDirLocationForText) - 1)
GetSubDir = sDirLocationForText

End Function
```

Currently when I call this function it returns all of the folder names, which is what it was intended for. However, is there a simple way to rework it so that it returns file names aswell? Thank you in advance.

[My Workbook](http://wikisend.com/download/806682/FileRename.xlsm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `vbNormal` in these lines instead of vbDirectory you should get files:

```
If IsMissing(sPattern) Then
   sDir = Dir$(sPath, vbDirectory)
Else
   sDir = Dir$(sPath & sPattern, vbDirectory)
End If
```

Comment: Just tried, it appears that nothing happens at all now, and nothing is printed to my intermediate window or my messagebox.

Comment: I just tested it and it produces lists of files.  How are you calling the function?  I tried ? GetSubDir(".", "*.*") and ? GetSubDir(".")

Comment: I did have to get rid of your on error line because you don't have that label.

Comment: sSubDir = GetSubDir(FolderName), I am not passing sPattern, could this be the cause? I have uploaded my workbook in the OP

Comment: Works just fine for me if you just pass the folder name...  Is it possible you made a typo or ?